# Which nodejs module to pick: node:http2 or node:https?

Tags: node.js, http, https, http2

As I understand, the purposes of both modules are orthogonal: even though HTTP/2 usually comes with HTTPs, both features are independent. It is clear to me that when I want to use HTTP2 I use `node:http2`, when HTTPS - `node:https`.

But what if I want both HTTP2 and HTTPS to be supported? Since I have to pick one, is `node:https` or `node:http2` capable of covering both features? If so, what is even the purpose of the other module, if its functionality can be fully replaced?

Also, if I don't know at all whether server supports HTTPs and HTTP/2, can I still safely use `node:https` or `node:http2` (i.e. will they fallback to plain http, http/1.1, for example, when I query `https://neverssl.com/` with them)? If so, is there still any purpose in `node:http`?